# Migrate procedural cache busting to PSR-6 cache pool service

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, apc, psr-6

Up till now our Doctrine entities did the cache busting via their `LifecycleEvents`. The APCu cache was deleted based on the entity's id in combination with a cache key constant:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 */
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
{
    apc_delete(sprintf(selff::CACHE_KEY, $event->getEntity()->getId()));
}
```

This was possible because of the procedural apc method, but this will never allow us to upgrade to PSR-6 because it makes use of a `CacheItemPool` that should be injected as a service.

As we will never going to inject the cache pool in the entities, my guess would be that we should create a `EventSubscriber` or `EventListener` for more than half the entities we have. This possible overhead frightens me a bit.

Will the subscriber / listener restructuring add a lot of overhead, and is that the right way to go? Should we add one global listener/subscriber for all entities (1..n) that handles all events or would it be better to add one listener/subscriber for every entity (n..m)?

Answer (score 0):

> > Will the subscriber / listener restructuring add a lot of overhead, and is that the right way to go?

`postPersist` method is also added as listener to doctrine `EventManager`. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html

Based on this I would guess that there would be no significant overhead.

However, I wouldn't base my decision on this but instead try it out. You can use Symfony profiler to see if any overhead exists and how big it is.
Really cool service I use for this kind of comparison is Blackfire.io.

> Should we add one global listener/subscriber for all entities (1..n) that handles all events or would it be better to add one listener/subscriber for every entity (n..m)?

I would create global listener for all entities. In case you need different caching logic for any particular entity you can always create separate case.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now thinking of adding a single listener and checking if `postPersist` and `preUpdate` methods exist. That way the invalidation logic can remain there at the entity level. The lifecycle events also set `dateModified`, which does not have a public setter.

Comment: Only thing different I would do is instead of checking if method exists is create CacheableEntityInterface and apply it to every entity that you want cached. It is much more sound to check type of object vs checking if it has a method.

Comment: Yes did that, next to that I'm using the Listener annotation, which seems to be the perfect solution: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners